# Session is not saved using Shared Preferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I have two activities.  In the first activity I have a login option and in the second activity, I have two buttons namely logout and close.
My question is when the user logs in and enters the second activity and when the user closes the app not logging out and again reopens the app then the second activity needs to be shown.

Here is my code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.user.store_session;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.media.session.MediaSessionManager;
import android.os.UserManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText name,password;
    Button login;
       public static final String ARB="ARBAZ";
       public static final String NAME="USERNAME";
    public static final String PASSWORD="PASSWORD";
       SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Edit_text_name);
        password=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_text_password);
        login=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_login);
        sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences(ARB, Context
                .MODE_PRIVATE);
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String name_=name.getText().toString();
                String pass=password.getText().toString();

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putString(NAME,name_); //NAME IS THE KEY VALUE
                editor.putString(PASSWORD,pass);
                editor.commit();

                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Main2Activity.java**

```
package com.example.user.store_session;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button logout,close;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        logout=(Button)findViewById(R.id.logout_button);
        close=(Button)findViewById(R.id.close_button);

        close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                finish();
            }
        });
        logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MainActivity.ARB, Context
                        .MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                editor.clear();
                editor.commit();

            }
        });
    }

}
```

I am not getting back the second activity after the app closes and reopens.

Comment: Am I right, if user is logged in you want to open Main2Activity when user opens your app?

Comment: Because You did not written any code for that . Just validate name and password for existence inside oncreate of first Activitiy . And if they exists finish it and launch the second Activitiy .

Comment: when user log in save a boolean that user already logged in  and put this check on very first of main activity that if this boolean exists or true then open second activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your MainActivity.java just check if the value NAME or PASSWORD exists.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.user.store_session;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.media.session.MediaSessionManager;
import android.os.UserManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText name,password;
    Button login;
       public static final String ARB="ARBAZ";
       public static final String NAME="USERNAME";
    public static final String PASSWORD="PASSWORD";
       SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Edit_text_name);
        password=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_text_password);
        login=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_login);
        sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences(ARB, Context
                .MODE_PRIVATE);
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String name_=name.getText().toString();
                String pass=password.getText().toString();

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putString(NAME,name_); //NAME IS THE KEY VALUE
                editor.putString(PASSWORD,pass);
                editor.commit();

                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

           // check if NAME have a value. If have value, user has been logged, so go to the second activity.
          if ( !sharedPreferences.getString("NAME","").equals("") || !sharedPreferences.getString("PASSWORD","").equals("") ){
                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
           }

    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need check the password, if you call `SharedPreferences.Editor.clean()` all fields are cleaned, so just check one is sufficient. However, I've edited the question

Comment: Main2activity.java is correct...There is need for rectification.

Comment: No, if you just check if User has logged, only changes MainActivity.java works. Main2Activity.java no need changes. Let me know if works.

Comment: In the if condition you are checking if the name field or password is null or not.My question is why you are firing 2nd activity if any one of them is null.

Comment: Well, as you clean the fields of SharedPreferences, all data is cleaned. So, the field of password and name has been cleaned, so for you know if user has logged off, just a field serves to prove that the data has been erased.

Comment: Happy to be able to help.

Comment: Can you solve my query....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49947911/how-to-fetch-image-from-gallery-in-circular-image-view